# caret moves 2 positions in stead of 1

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have the strangest issue in Flex!
Consider an `<mx:TextInput />` with text. This textbox has focus and a nice little caret blinking inside. Now when you press the `->` or `<-` button, the caret moves **two** positions instead of **one**! Also when you press the `delete` button, it removes two characters instead of one.
This only occurs in Firefox, but it's not a FF bug because it only happens in my application...
Anyone have an idea what might cause this bizzare bug?

Comment: Do you have any code wich could affect the behavior of your textinput? If you start an empty project with only a TextInput, does it happen too?

Comment: I'm working with two projects and they both have the same problem, but indeed when I start a new project, it works fine. Maybe it's a bug in one of the libs I'm using. I'm gonna test that now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug appears when the Flash plugin is created with `wmode="opaque"` or `wmode="transparent"`. Two solutions:

- Upgrade to a newer version of Firefox (the issue is fixed in 3.6).
- Use `wmode="window"`.

Comment: Excelent. However, I can't use wmode="window" because I'm using an HTMLComponent that depends on wmode="opaque". When I upgraded from ff 3.5.7 to 3.6 it was fixed!

Comment: +1 @Maurits Upgrading your browser doesn't fix the issue - clients might be using FF2 or FSM forbid, IE6.

Comment: @Amarghosh: That's definitely true, but at least we can say we found the source of the problem and we're one step closer to fixing it.